Stacks Editor is doing rapid layout shift as I edit the body input
When I edit my input in an inline answer editor on MSO (and only on MSO- not SO or MSE), almost every time the input changes, the editor / editor preview render experiences a brief layout shift. Ex. each time I type a character. It's extremely annoying.
I'm opted in to the new editor on MSO, and I use the Markdown with Preview mode.
Why is this happening? Is it related in any way to what appears to be an MSO test with GitHub links oneboxing?

This bug is specific to the Stacks Editor and easily reproducible with it.  (I concur with your assessment of "extremely annoying", though I hadn't yet gotten to writing it up.)  I assume you have "Enable new editor" turned on?

Reproduced it: 1. go to profile preferences 2. Enable new editor (ON) 3. Try to type an answer or edit (same result) 4. set the editor to "Markdown with preview" (top right has three modes, that's the right-most one). 5. Almost every keystroke causes the preview to disappear and re-appear. I couldn't capture a video of it - the software I have doesn't grab enough frames to show the issue.

I can reproduce this in the Staging Ground as well but it occurs very infrequently.

@VLAZ thanks. yeah I tried to capture with chrome devtools, but couldn't get the rapid flashing. I did notice a call to something called flush in the flame chart. wonder if that's related at all.

I can reproduce it on MSE, as well. Same as here on MSO - most input causes a visible flicker (say, 8 of 10 or so). I could reproduce it on SG but as @AbdulAzizBarkat said - extremely rare. I managed to see one flicker in maybe 20-ish keystrokes.

Is this the problem you are referring to? (In reality the flickers are more frequent, but as @VLAZ mentioned, the framerate of the capturing software is too low). I produced this result in the answer of this question.

@JeanotZubler yep, that's what I'm seeing. And yes, seems to happen in every single place the editor is - questions, answers, edits. Doesn't seem to matter.

Sniff sniff. I am smelling... a problem caused by a promise. If something is wrapped in a promise, it will be resolved at the soonest the next "tick" as it goes onto the event loop so that leaves a small window of time open for a div to be blank whereas without the promise it would just be blank and filled within the same tick.

Seems to also appear on SO as I explained on my question

@Elikill58 just to confirm (since I didn't try it before) - yes, happens with the Ask Wizard (which uses the new editor). Same frequency as on MSO or MSE - a lot. Currently, it seems that only in Staging Ground it doesn't happen too much.
